# Get the post thumbnail URL and assign to variable

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having a very strange issue. All I want to do is get the thumbnail url and assign it to a variable. Here is my code.

```
<?php /* Template for displaying content of MH Posts Large widget */ ?>

<article class="post-<?php the_ID(); ?> mh-posts-large-item">
<figure class="mh-posts-large-thumb">

<?php

$form_image = 'blank';

if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
        $form_image = the_post_thumbnail_url('mh-magazine-lite-content');

?>
```

Basically, if the post has a thumbnail I want to store the actual URL of the thumbnail used in that variable for later use. However, instead of doing that it just prints the URL on screen and doesn't actually seem to put it in the variable.

I don't understand why and I would definitely appreciate any help! :)

Comment: Try using `get_the_post_thumbnail_url` instead

Comment: Absolutely right - I pulled up the two functions side by side and noticed the very subtle difference that one 'displays' and the other 'returns'. /headdesk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [official documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail_url/):

```
function the_post_thumbnail_url( $size = 'post-thumbnail' ) {
    $url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( null, $size );
    if ( $url ) {
        echo esc_url( $url );
    }
}
```

So `the_post_thumbnail_url` only outputs the URL it gets from `get_the_post_thumbnail_url` and doesn't return anything. Thus the solution is to use `get_the_post_thumbnail_url` directly.